# Tapestry5 : No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-plugin, tapestry

i using tapestry 5 with spring and hibernate,i try to build my application throw's me this exception???!!!???what is problem ,any suggesyion will be such a relif????

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.fit:rent-a-car:war:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 194, column 18
[WARNING] 'reporting.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 235, column 17
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
.....
.....

[ERROR] ioc.Registry No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.
[ERROR] ioc.Registry Operations trace:

[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 1] Realizing service ApplicationInitializer

[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 2] Invoking org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.buildApplicationInitializer(Logger, List) (at TapestryModule.java:1458)

[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 3] Determining injection value for parameter #2 (java.util.List)

[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 4] Collecting ordered configuration for service ApplicationInitializer

[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 5] Invoking method org.apache.tapestry5.spring.SpringModule.contributeApplicationInitializer(OrderedConfiguration, ApplicationContext) (at SpringModule.java:54).

[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 6] Determining injection value for parameter #2 (org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)

[ERROR] ioc.Registry [ 7] Resolving object of type org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext using MasterObjectProvider
[ERROR] TapestryModule.ApplicationInitializer Construction of service ApplicationInitializer failed: Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.buildApplicationInitializer(Logger, List) (at TapestryModule.java:1458) (for service 'ApplicationInitializer'): Error invoking service contribution method org.apache.tapestry5.spring.SpringModule.contributeApplicationInitializer(OrderedConfiguration, ApplicationContext): No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking service builder method org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule.buildApplicationInitializer(Logger, List) (at TapestryModule.java:1458) (for service 'ApplicationInitializer'): Error invoking service contribution method org.apache.tapestry5.spring.SpringModule.contributeApplicationInitializer(OrderedConfiguration, ApplicationContext): No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:76)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackingObjectCreator$1.invoke(OperationTrackingObjectCreator.java:45)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.invoke(RegistryImpl.java:1063)
    at ......

    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking service contribution method org.apache.tapestry5.spring.SpringModule.contributeApplicationInitializer(OrderedConfiguration, ApplicationContext): No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.invokeMethod(ContributionDefImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ContributionDefImpl.contribute(ContributionDefImpl.java:82)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl$9.run(RegistryImpl.java:651)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl$1.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:50)org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.createObject(ServiceBuilderMethodInvoker.java:56)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException: No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.logAndRethrow(OperationTrackerImpl.java:102)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.invoke(OperationTrackerImpl.java:69)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.invoke(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:68)
    ....
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No service implements the interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext.
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.getService(RegistryImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.ObjectLocatorImpl.getService(ObjectLocatorImpl.java:45)...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the tapestry-spring dependency

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
     <artifactId>tapestry-spring</artifactId>
     <version>[your-tapestry-version]</version>
   </dependency>
```

What tapestry version are you using? I believe in 5.0 tapestry expects the `ApplicationContext` to be in the `ServletContext`. Other than that, check the [documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/integrating-with-spring-framework.html) like @Ryan Steward suggested.

Comment: hi i figure out what is problem ???depedency what you suggest was superfluous in pom.xml i removed ,now build application ok.....thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Tapestry, but it looks like it just can't find your Spring context. Have you followed the instructions for [integrating Tapestry with Spring](http://tapestry.apache.org/integrating-with-spring-framework.html)? Have you verified that Spring is actually starting?

Comment: Yup. Is Spring even on the classpath?